# Can I use centOS and Redhat's JDK-11 altogether in my production server

Tags: centos, rhel, openjdk

As per the Oracle OpenJDK policy, there will not have any LTS support anymore, but Redhat OpenJDK will continue to have LTS support so far we have seen. Our current server is based on CentOS 7 and Oracle JDK-8 and wants to migrate some sort of free JDK11 solutions with LTS support for our production server.

I've not found any option to download or install redhat's openJDK-11 in cent-os. I can't even install it in RHEL-server without subscription. Is there any licencing problem if I use cent-OS and redhat-openJDK-11?

Comment: The licensing part is the lesser of your problems. Retro compatibility in supporting java frameworks does not work particularly well. I would ask oracle instead. You can always test it on a pre production environment

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK 8 and 11 are available in the CentOS repositories:

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
yum install java-11-openjdk
```

As far as contractual support goes, you should ask your Red Hat sales representative about your specific requirements.